# How is "Humans need not apply" a correct sentence?

Tags: word-choice, expressions, phrase-meaning

I saw this expression as a title of a short documentary on Youtube and was wondering, because it makes no sense to me grammatically.

Comment: Can you explain why you think it's ungrammatical? Seems perfectly standard to me.

Comment: @Catija never saw that construction before, the way I would say it  "Humans don't need to apply"

Comment: I suppose that you could consider it a form of shorthand. The context for this text is generally on a sign or placard, so brevity is preferred.

Answer (score 1):

It is a correct sentence.  Compare it to "You need not apply for this job.".  It's the same thing, but with the "for this job" implied.

Historically this phrase was used in a context (classified ad, window of a shop) that made it clear what the undesired group was not to apply for.  So a shop might have had a sign up saying "Irish need not apply".